# NancyFx : DateTime as Json in request body

Tags: .net, json, nancy

Not sure if this is a general json issue or something specific to Nancy.  I want to pass a datetime as json in the body of a request.  Using the same approach I use use for my dto's fails. A DateTime is created server side, but it is Datetime.Min not the value set client side:

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Nancy;
using Nancy.Testing;
using Nancy.ModelBinding;

namespace Test
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class ScratchNancy
    {
        [Test]
        public void RootTest()
        {
            var dateTime = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2000");

            var result = new Browser(new DefaultNancyBootstrapper()).Post(
                "/",
                with =>
                {
                    with.HttpRequest();
                    with.JsonBody(dateTime);
                });

            Assert.AreEqual(dateTime, result.Body.DeserializeJson<DateTime>());
        }

        public class RootModule : NancyModule
        {
            public RootModule()
            {
                Post["/"] = Root;
            }

            private Response Root(dynamic o)
            {
                var dt = this.Bind<DateTime>(); //Returns 1/1/0001

                return Response.AsJson(dt);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the content of the body should be serialised to json. I'm not on a dev machine now will try it when I am. :) try putting this `/Date(1224043200000)/` in the  `with.JsonBody`.

Comment: I ran your test and it passed without modification.

Comment: I edited your test code to make it fail (for the right reason).

Comment: I looks like, at some point, Nancy's JSON serializer is converting the datetime to `\Date(946706400000)\`. I don't see how it's trying to convert it back, so it's a mystery to me.